# Ajax update a field with it's ID doesn't work with rendered attribute on Primefaces

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I am having a small issue with `ajax` and `rendered` attribute when `update` is triggered on a `selectOneMenu`.

Following is the code for the `selectOneMenu`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span10 margin-bottom-10">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="hcg-control-label span5">Τύπος Παραγώμενου Εγγράφου</label>
                <div class="controls span7">
                   <p:selectOneMenu id="ProducedDocumentType" value="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.cAType.producedDocument}" style="width:100%">
                     <p:ajax event="change" update=":cATypeForm:UploadFileWidget" immediate="true" process="@this"/>
                     <f:selectItems value="#{enumsBean.producedDocumentTypes}" var="myVar" itemValue="#{myVar}" itemLabel="#{myVar.label}" />
                   </p:selectOneMenu>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which produces the following:
[image]

And I have an `inputText` field followed by a `fileUpload`:

```
<h:panelGroup id="UploadFileWidget" rendered="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.cAType.producedDocument ne 'withoutDocument'}" >
    <div class="row">
                <div class="span10 margin-bottom-10">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="hcg-control-label span5">Πρότυπο Εγγράφου</label>
                        <div class="controls span7">
                            <div class="hcg-input-group">
                                <p:inputText id="TemplateFile" styleClass="hcg-full-width" required="true" value="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.cAType.template.fileName}" readonly="true" requiredMessage="Δεν έχετε επιλέξει πρότυπο εγγράφου!"/>
                                <span class="hcg-input-group-btn">
                                    <p:commandButton id="TemplateFileDownload" styleClass="btn btn-default" icon="fa fa-download" actionListener="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.downloadTemplateFile}" disabled="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.cAType.template.fileName == null}" />
                                    <p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default" id="TemplateFileDelete" icon="fa fa-times" actionListener="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.deleteTemplateFile}" disabled="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.cAType.template.fileName == null}" />
                                </span>
                            </div> 

                             <p:fileUpload id="uploadFile" value="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.uploadedTemplateFile}" fileUploadListener="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.handleTemplateFileUpload}"
                             label="Επιλέξτε" uploadLabel="Ανέβασμα" cancelLabel="Ακύρωση" update=":cATypeForm:TemplateFile,:cATypeForm:TemplateFileDownload,:cATypeForm:TemplateFileDelete" styleClass="hcg-upload" />                         
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Which produces the following:
[image]

The requirement is to have the whole `panelGroup` rendered only when the the user chooses one of the first two values of the dropdown list. I can manage to make it work only when the `update` attribute
is as follows: `update="@form"`, but I don't want to use it because when this happens, details on other fields of the same form are refreshed and the user has to rewrite the from the start. I want to update only the panelGroup, so I tried it with its id (as seen in code above), but nothing happens.

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by doing the following. I changed the update to:

```xml
    <p:ajax event="change" update=":cATypeForm:UploadFileWidget"/>
```

Then i wrapped the whole `<div class="row">` of the `<h:panelGroup>` with a `<ui:fragment>` and the final code is as follows:

```xml
    <h:panelGroup id="UploadFileWidget">
      <ui:fragment rendered="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.cAType.producedDocument ne 'withoutDocument'}">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="span10 margin-bottom-10">
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="hcg-control-label span5">Πρότυπο Εγγράφου</label>
                 <div class="controls span7">
                   <div class="hcg-input-group">
                     <p:inputText id="TemplateFile" styleClass="hcg-full-width" required="true" value="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.cAType.template.fileName}" readonly="true" requiredMessage="Δεν έχετε επιλέξει πρότυπο εγγράφου!"/>
                       <span class="hcg-input-group-btn">
                          <p:commandButton id="TemplateFileDownload" styleClass="btn btn-default" icon="fa fa-download" actionListener="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.downloadTemplateFile}" disabled="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.cAType.template.fileName == null}" />
                          <p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default" id="TemplateFileDelete" icon="fa fa-times" actionListener="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.deleteTemplateFile}" disabled="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.cAType.template.fileName == null}" />
                       </span>
                    </div> 
        
                    <p:fileUpload id="uploadFile" value="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.uploadedTemplateFile}" fileUploadListener="#{certificateTypeRegisterView.handleTemplateFileUpload}"
                                     label="Επιλέξτε" uploadLabel="Ανέβασμα" cancelLabel="Ακύρωση" update=":cATypeForm:TemplateFile,:cATypeForm:TemplateFileDownload,:cATypeForm:TemplateFileDelete" styleClass="hcg-upload" />                         
                   </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </ui:fragment>
     </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: You did not have to change to `f:ajax` your `p:ajax` was fine your correct solution was wrapping the outer component and updating that so the rendered flag inside of it gets re-eavlaued.  JSF wont update a field that is rendered="false" because its not even in the JSF tree.  By wrapping it in an outer component that is visible the `update=""` works now.  So i would put your `p:ajax` back.. This is a common mistake people make with JSF and `rendered` field.